# AngularJS displaying image using base64 string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I have an image stored in my database and I want to use angular to display it.
The HTML for my page looks like this:

```
<img ng-if="controller.model.logo && !controller.result" ng-src="{{ controller.model.logo }}" />
```

And the model looks like this:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Test",
    "logo":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhGAQHAfcAAI6Sls3O1NPT1picpLq9xfv47t/j5ZWWm73Dy…I+amVcIIqn6qQAIVtzzkZiomiCBB0lMUMqg79LXKqAJJL3xuJe4hwBRiB9CV9CgpcsNzECAgA7",
    "theme":"black",
    "centers":null
}
```

but the image is not displaying. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img ng-if="controller.model.logo && !controller.result" ng-src="{{controller.model.logo}}" />
```

using string interpolation for the `ng-src` attribute

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my example

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```html
<img ng-if="controller.model.logo && !controller.result" ng-src="{{controller.model.logo}}" />
```